# Minimum Match Logic

Tags: php, logic

I have a very large data set that I'm trying to find the smallest set that will satisfy all the data sets. The final set must have one value in it that is in all of the data sets

A small sample of the data looks like

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21
        [1] => 21
        [2] => 21
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 29
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 27
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21
        [1] => 21
        [2] => 21
        [3] => 39
        [4] => 39
        [5] => 43
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 29
        [1] => 33
        [2] => 33
        [3] => 43
    )
```

In this case I need logic to return 21, 27 and 29
The values returned needs to be be the minium number of values that match all arrays. Since I'm a PHP programmer, I writing this function in PHP.

Comment: So basically, you want the smallest common elements.

Comment: This can be optimized quite a bit. Each array should be reduced to distinct elements. If any array is a superset of another, it can be deleted. Not sure about the rest, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow this algorithm:

**Updated after testing**

```
$data=array(
            array(21,29,27,57,22),
            array(22,21,23,24,25,26),
            array(31)
            );

$map = array(); // keep a map of values and how many times they occur in other sets
foreach ($data as $setid => $set) {
    foreach (array_unique($set) as $v) {
        $map[$v][$setid] = true;
    }
}

function reverseCount(array $a, array $b)
{
    return count($b) - count($a);
}

// sort reversed on intersection count
uasort($map, 'reverseCount');

// after sorting the first number will be the one that occurs the most
// keep track of which sets have been hit
$setmap = array(); $n = count($data);
foreach ($map as $v => $sets) {
    $hits = 0;
    foreach ($sets as $setid => $dummy) {
        if (!isset($setmap[$setid])) {
            --$n;
            ++$hits;
            $setmap[$setid] = true;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    if ($hits) {
        echo "value $v\n";
        if (!$n) {
            // all sets are hit
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Tested this time. It's not proven to always get the right result, because this is considered a greedy approximation algorithm.

But I hope it gives an idea of what you could do. Let me know if anything confuses you or if I'm dead wrong about it :)

Comment: given the data set from timus2001 above, I don't see the answer outputted in $setmap or $map. I like the idea of mapping results, I'll try working through that.

Comment: @DavidFairbanks that gives 22 and 31, the answer is not in `$map` or `$setmap` themselves btw ... it's distilled from both; and again, this algorithm will not always give the most optimal results because for that you will probably need dynamic programming

Comment: That seems to be it. I'll do further testing. Thanks

Comment: Why such a complicated algorithm ? @DavidFairbanks what about my answer ?

Comment: @pomeh when OP said 'minimal' he didn't mean the lowest number of a set; he means the smallest set of numbers that is present in all sets.

Comment: @Jack ow ok my mistake, I understand it now :)